# Add a watermark to photo before it's shared on social media

Tags: java, android, android-camera, watermark

I've successfully added a watermark to the preview of the camera image that the user takes on my android app, however when it's sent to Instagram or Tumblr, the watermark isn't there. 
I believe this is because it is sharing the image from local storage, and has nothing to do with the preview.

I think I need to modify the 'take picture' code for the camera, so that when it takes the photo it converts it to a bitmap, adds it to a canvas with the watermark and then saves it, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I believe this is the source of the file being shared

```
final File fileToUpload = new File(StorageUtils.getStoragePath(ShareActivity.this), StorageUtils.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
```

Here is the take picture code for the camera.

```
protected void takePicture() {
    if (cameraPreview == null) return;
    Camera camera = cameraPreview.getCamera();
    if (camera == null) return;

    camera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            if (data == null || data.length == 0) return;

            File imageFile = new File(StorageUtils.getStoragePath(CameraActivity.this), StorageUtils.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
            File parentDir = imageFile.getParentFile();

            if (!parentDir.exists()) {
                if (!parentDir.mkdirs()) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create directory: " + parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
                    return;
                }
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to save file: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            //workaround for bug with facing camera introduced (intentionally?) in 4.0+
            if (isCameraFacingFront && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                //flip image vertically
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
                bitmap.recycle();
                try {
                    rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(imageFile));
                    rotatedBitmap.recycle();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to rotate and save bitmap: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, ShareActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ShareActivity.PARAM_IMAGE_FILE, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if (business != null)
                intent.putExtra(ShareActivity.PARAM_BUSINESS, business);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Or I may be way off base. Any help or pointing in the right direction is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're on the right track. After you've gotten the picture, decode it, create a new Canvas for it, draw the watermark on the canvas, and save that image. You're pretty much just going to repeat the code for flipping the image, just drawing on the canvas right before saving the new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to my comment of, "You're on the right track. After you've gotten the picture, decode it, create a new Canvas for it, draw the watermark on the canvas, and save that image. You're pretty much just going to repeat the code for flipping the image, just drawing on the canvas right before saving the new image."...

I got bored and did it for you:

```
protected void takePicture() {
    if (cameraPreview == null) return;
    Camera camera = cameraPreview.getCamera();
    if (camera == null) return;

    camera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File imageFile = new File(StorageUtils.getStoragePath(CameraActivity.this), StorageUtils.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
            File parentDir = imageFile.getParentFile();
            if(!createImageFromCamera(data, imageFile, parentDir) return;

            //workaround for bug with facing camera introduced (intentionally?) in 4.0+
            boolean requiresImageFlip = isCameraFacingFront && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;

            Bitmap adjustedBitmap = getBitmap(imageFile, requiresImageFlip);
            if(!drawWatermark(adjustedBitmap)) return;
            if(!saveImage(imageFile, adjustedBitmap)) return;

            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, ShareActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ShareActivity.PARAM_IMAGE_FILE, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if(business != null) intent.putExtra(ShareActivity.PARAM_BUSINESS, business);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(File imageFile, boolean flipVertically){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    if(flipVertically){
        matrix.setRotate(180);
        matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
    }

    Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    bitmap.recycle();

    return adjustedBitmap;
}

private boolean saveImage(File imageFile, Bitmap bitmap){
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(imageFile));
        bitmap.recycle();
        return true;
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to rotate and save bitmap: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean drawWatermark(Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(watermarkBitmap); // However you're drawing the watermark on the canvas
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean createImageFromCamera(byte[] data, File imageFile, File parentDir){
    if (data == null || data.length == 0) return false;

    if (!parentDir.exists()) {
        if (!parentDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to create directory: " + parentDir.getAbsolutePath());
            return false;    
        }        
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to save file: " + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Replace your entire takePicture() method with that and it should do everything you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you!! It seems like it fixes all of the fun errors I was getting trying to solve this on my own, but when I take the picture now I get a java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed at : camera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {   I'll try to troubleshoot the problem, but if you know off the top of your head what's happening that's fine too!

Comment: You're very welcome! And hmmm, your logcat should point to the line where the exception is occurring, or is it not? Or could the issue be related to the the call to the camera?

Comment: I commented out these two lines which the logcat was pointing out, and it doesn't crash? Thanks again for your time           if(!drawWatermark(adjustedBitmap)) return;
if(!saveImage(imageFile, adjustedBitmap)) return;

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? Also, the drawWatermark method needs to be configured to actually draw the watermark the way you're doing it over the camera preview